# os.system() save files to certain location

Tags: python, directory, operating-system

The next code saves three files in C:/Users/user1:

```
os.system("ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i audio.mp3 -c copy output.mp4")
```

How can I make it save in another directory?

Comment: Write a different path than `output.mp4`, including some directories?

Comment: How to format the path?

Comment: I don't know exactly, did you try something and it didn't work? For example `some_dir/output.mp4` or `some_dir\\output.mp4`? What happened?

Comment: Using `/` like in `some_dir/output.mp4` works perfectly. Thank you.